# Android Studio gradle failed to resolve for SDK version 16

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just installed Android Studio for a new class and I can't even run a HelloWorld program. There are no third party dependencies as I literally just installed Android Studio, SDK version 16, the latest support repository, latest build tools, and created a Nexus 5 AVD running 4.1.2 (16). I keep getting

```
"Error:(24,13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.appcompat-v7:16.+"
```

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edu.usna.mobileos.hellooooworld"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:16.+' // line giving me the error
}
```

I've tried many other solutions I've found online, but none have worked so far. I need to work with API version 16 (Android 4.1.2) in this class, so using a newer API isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:16.+'` **doesn't exist.**

Use the **latest version** and pay attention using the `+` because it is **not a good option**.In this way you will not be able to replicate the build in the future.

> I need to work with API version 16 (Android 4.1.2) in this class, so using a newer API isn't an option.

**Don't confuse minSdk and the compileSdk**.

The **compileSdkVersion** is your way to tell Gradle what version of the Android SDK to compile your app with.
If `compileSdkVersion` sets the newest APIs available to you, **minSdkVersion** is the lower bound for your app. The `minSdkVersion` is one of the signals the Google Play Store uses to determine which of a user’s devices an app can be installed on.

More info [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.wqpesz3ff).

You can use one of these versions.
Check your sdk for updated version:

```
  //it requires compileSdkVersion 23
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 22
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

  //it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

Also there are very old version:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
```

Comment: Where do you get those version lists from?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Here you can find all the archive. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html

Answer (score 0):

Inside Android Studio click the icon below to open the SDK Manager:

[image]

From there you should see something like this:

[image]

You want to update and/or install Android Support Library.  You also may need to update the version your build.gradle file is pointing to.  For example, the version I have is 23.1.0, so my reference would look like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+' // line giving me the error
```

Comment: I already had Android Support Library installed and updated, but changing that line broke it even worse. I'm now seeing 120 "No resource found..." and "Error retrieving parent..." errors.

Comment: What did you try?  What version of Android Support Library is installed?  What version are you referencing in your build.gradle?